# how to unit test if an C# event is handled or not?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have a form with a button and attached method. 
that is all in the designer.cs file.
Sometimes it get overwritten by some other developer, using the designer.

I want to make a unit test that checks that delegate operation is assigned in the designer. How would you do that?

```
x.button.click += aFunction;

private void aFunction(arg1,arg2)
{
     //do something, but change no state.
}
```

Comment: cannot check if x.button.click != null?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4436207/how-to-unit-test-in-c-that-a-button-is-clicked